# How i update mern 2.0 react version to (react v16.5.1)?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack, mern

I am trying to update the react version in the mern 2.0 boilerplate but, have lots of issues to update.

I had got some util error in this code.

**Warning: Accessing PropTypes via the main React package is deprecated, and will be removed in  React v16.0. Use the latest available v15.* prop-types package from npm instead. For info on usage, compatibility, migration and more ...**

**Warning: Accessing createClass via the main React package is deprecated, and will be removed in React v16.0. Use a plain JavaScript class instead. If you're not yet ready to migrate, create-react-class v15.* is available on npm as a temporary, drop-in replacement ...**

Answer (score 0):

So you need to install 
`npm prop-types` 
use prop types in your js file like this:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
//get rid of this line below with propTypes
import { PropTypes } from 'react' 

class Greeting extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Hello Mario! My name is {this.props.name}</h1>
    );
  }
}

Greeting.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string
};
```

Make sure you remove reference in your React class js file 
`import {Proptypes} from React`